# Can I pull data directly from hive table to H2O?

Tags: hadoop, hive, h2o

We have our data stored in hive text files and parquet files is there anyway to load directly from these into H2O or do we have to go through an intermediate step like csv or pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can find all the information you need [here](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/getting-data-into-h2o.html?highlight=hive)

H2O currently supports the following file types:

- CSV (delimited) files (including GZipped CSV)
- ORC
- SVMLight
- ARFF
- XLS
- XLSX
- Avro version 1.8.0 (without multifile parsing or column type modification)
- **Parquet**

Notes:

- ORC is available only if H2O is running as a Hadoop job.
- **Users can also import Hive files that are saved in ORC format.**
- When doing a parallel data import into a cluster:

  - If the data is an unzipped csv file, H2O can do offset reads, so each node in your cluster can be directly reading its part of the csv file in parallel.
  - If the data is zipped, H2O will have to read the whole file and unzip it before doing the parallel read.
    So, if you have very large data files reading from HDFS, it is best to use unzipped csv. But if the data is further away than the LAN, then it is best to use zipped csv.

Comment: Thanks Lauren,  I have seen this before but I haven't seen any examples of how to pull from Parquet, ORC, or a TextFile stored in HDFS.  We currently either load into a Pandas DataFrame or create a temporary table with a comma delimiter,  But these create additional overhead in the job that I would like to remove.

Comment: have you tried passing in the path to the parquet file or text file? you can use h2o.import_file(hdfs://path/to/myfile.parquet) in python for example or h2o.importFile(hdfs://path/to/myfile.csv) in R.

Comment: Lauren I have tried the Python example you gave me and I keep getting an offset error  ~/.conda/envs/myJupyterKernel35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/h2o/h2o.py:522: UserWarning: ParseError at file (file path) at byte offset 61608; error = 'Unmatched quote char "'
  warnings.warn(w)  I have recreated the table with a very small subset of the data 5 rows x 3 columns and still get this error not sure where its finding this 61608 because the new table is no where near that big,

Comment: is it possible for you to post an example of the data so I can see if I can reproduce the error. Parsing errors like that can happen if you have text columns with returns or newlines in them.